# Building C++ cross-platform static libraries

Tags: c++, cross-platform, static-libraries

I want to build cross-platform statically linked library in C++.

How am I supposed to do this(I am a complete NOOB, never been using g++,gcc,mingw etc I looked on the internet for a solution to my problem, but didn't find anything. Except that mingw is a Minimalist GNU for Windows...)? I've been always using Visual c++ on windows, but now I have to build lib which will be attached to Qt projects for: windows,mac,linux.

If anyone know a good tutorial, on using compilers, and how to build libraries, I'll appreciate sharing them here :)

Thanks, **may the force be with you**.

Comment: I would forget even attempting it. This is not something a "noob" should be doing.

Comment: I mean I'll include them to Qt app, which will be used on mac,windows,linux. My problem derivatives from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236603/freetype2-lib-in-qt-problem-with-building

Comment: Your problem derives from you being new to Qt itself and Mac and Linux. You should learn Qt and meanwhile search someone proficient with Qt and Mac and someone proficient with Qt and Linux into your team.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "cross-platform statically linked C++ library". You have to compile the library for each platform separately. The *source code* for your library can be cross-platform though.

Comment: @Oo Tiib: I just wrote a Qt utility app in Windows and it worked out of the box when I compiled and ran in Linux (using Qt Creator on each platform). I'm sure it would be just as easy on Mac. Using Qt, having a specialist for each platform is overkill unless it's for some major application like a full-blown web browser or a word processor. If you know Qt on one platform, you know it for all platforms.

Comment: @Emilie Cormier: The people familiar with a platform are still always needed to avoid making something that does not fit with that platform. Even if it works, the customers will discard it as alien.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW is a very good compiler! I use it all the time. Even though MinGW stands for Minimalist GNU for Windows, MinGW has everything you need to program in either C++ or C. If you are creating a QT Application, I recommend using QT Creator (just google it). I haven't used it lately, but I think it supports Cross-Platform compiling (as does MinGW, with some command-line commands...).

The best way to cross-compile though, is but getting a copy of each OS that you are going to compile for. So if you are doing Windows, Mac, and Linux, I recommend getting one of each (Mac OS X is around $25 and Linux is free). Then just use the included compilers (XCode on Mac; GCC on Linux) to compile. Unfortunately when you are performing cross compiling, you need to support each OS individually (some parts can shared between OSes).

Since you will be using a toolkit (QT), you probably don't have to worry much about platform specific calls or anything. Just make sure you use the QT typedefs and structs and not the Microsoft Windows ones...

Comment: You mean s/he should use Microsoft QT typedefs and structs and not Microsoft Windows ones :-)

Comment: Yeah, use the ones provided by QT rather than the ones provided by the Windows SDK ("wtypes.h"or "wctypes.h").

Comment: Perhaps you should find out what "cross-compile" means before posting on the subject?

Comment: Maybe my problem is different-> why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236603/freetype2-lib-in-qt-problem-with-building lib built with Qt caused errors, but one downloaded from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm didn't?

Comment: Mine was only a bad joke about MS that acquired^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hsigned a partnership with Nokia that is the owner of QT